# How to get value from dynamically filled drop down on button click in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am stuck in getting value from drop down. Drop down is dynamically filled from sql server database. 
Dropdown 1 displays product name and it is dynamically filled. 
Dropdown 2 displays environment name and it is filled by HTML.

I am getting value of environment but not product. 
Please help me. Thanks

Here is the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">

//Dropdown 1
<p>Product Name:
<select name="productname">
  <option value="">Select</option>

<?php
if( $conn ) 
{
    $sql_dd = "SELECT ProductName from Product";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_dd );
        if( $stmt === false) {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt );
    if ($rows === false)
        echo "There is no data. <br />";
    else 
    {    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
           echo "<option value=''>".$row['ProductName']."</option>";
    }
}
?>

//Dropdown 2
Client Type: 
<select name="environment" style="width: 10%;">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="en1">en1</option>
<option value="en2">en2</option>
<option value="en3">en3</option>
</select>&emsp;
<input type="submit" class="theme-btn" value="Search" name="submit"/>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $productname = $_POST['productname'];
    $environment= $_POST['environment'];

echo "productname: ".$productname." environment: ".$environment;
}?>
```

Comment: Your product options don't have values.

Comment: `<option value=''>` that is why

Comment: perhaps, its better to select `productid` and `productname` and print the `productid` in the option value attribute as @nogad said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not added
this:

```
echo "<option value=''>".$row['ProductName']."</option>";
```

should be

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['ProductName'] . "'>". $row['ProductName'] ."</option>";
```

Comment: no select is not missing `<select name="productname">`